# Can we get the concentration inequality of the inner product of two unit vectors distributed on the sphere?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

Let $u$ and $v$ be two random vectors on $R^n$ that are independent and uniformly distributed on the unit sphere. That means we can represent it as Gaussian random vectors $g\sim N(0, I_n)$, $$u=\frac{g}{\|g\|_2}.
$$

But do we have the concentration inequality of the $u\cdot v$? That looks like $$P(u\cdot v\le x)\ge 1-Ce^{-c x}$$

Comment: Do you mean $P(u\cdot v \le x) \ge \ldots$?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I do not know the direction. Maybe it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ let $X_1,X_2\sim\mathcal N(0,I_n)$ be two $n$-variate independent standard normal random vectors. Further, let $X^\circ_i=\frac{1}{\|X_i\|_2}X_i$ for $i=1,2$ (which is well-defined since $\|X_i\|_2>0$ almost surely). Notice that $X^\circ_1$ and $X^\circ_2$ are independent uniformly distributed points on the unit sphere. Let $x\cdot y=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i$ denote the inner product for $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$.

Claim: There exists $a,b\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ and all $t\in\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ we have
$$\mathbb P(|X^\circ_1\cdot X^\circ_2|\ge t)\le ae^{-bt^2n}.$$

Remark: This is sometimes referred to as sub-gaussian concentration.

Proof:
First, recall the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) and notice that $|X^\circ_1\cdot X^\circ_2|\le 1$ almost surely.
Next, for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and using $Z_i=\|X_i\|_2$ we show that for all $n$, $t$ we have $\mathbb P(Z_i^2\le(1-t)n)\le\exp(-\frac{1}{4}t^2n)$.
Let $X_i=(X_{i,j})_{j=1,\dots,n}$ and [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Other_properties) that the random variables (rvs) $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are mutually independent (the offdiagonal entries in the covariance matrix $I_n$ are $0$) standard normal rvs. This shows that $Z_i^2=\sum_{j=1}^nX_{i,j}^2$ follows a [Chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with $n$ degrees of freedom. Hence, the [Laurent-Massart bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Concentration) yields $\mathbb P(n-Z_i^2\ge 2\sqrt{nt})\le e^{-t}$, or equivalently $\mathbb P(Z_i^2\le(1-t)n)\le\exp(-\frac{1}{4}t^2n)$.

Now, we show that for all $n$, $t$ we have $P(n,t)=\mathbb P(|X_1\cdot X_2|\ge tn)\le 2\exp(-f(t)t^2n)$ with
$$f(t)=f(t,\lambda(t))=\frac{\ln(1-\lambda(t)^2)}{2t^2}+\frac{\lambda(t)}{t}$$
for $t>0$ and $f(0)=f(0,\lambda(0))=\frac{1}{2}$, where $\lambda(t)=\frac{1}{2t}(\sqrt{1+4t}-1)$ and $\lambda(0)=0$.
Notice that this holds for $t=0$ because $P(n,0)\le 1<2=e^{-f(0)0^2n}$, so let $t>0$. Recall the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Other_properties), let $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and notice that
$$P_+(n,t)=\mathbb P(X_1\cdot X_2\ge tn)
=\mathbb P\left(e^{\lambda X_1\cdot X_2}\ge e^{\lambda tn}\right)
\le\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X_1\cdot X_2}]e^{-\lambda tn}.$$
Now, notice that $X_1\cdot X_2=\sum_{j=1}^nX_{1,j}X_{2,j}$ is a sum of $n$ i.i.d. rvs, since $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent and hence $X_{1,1},\dots,X_{1,n},X_{2,1},\dots,X_{2,n}$ are mutually independent standard normal rvs by the above.
Thus, we have $\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X_1\cdot X_2}]=\mathbb E[\prod_{j=1}^ne^{\lambda X_{1,j}X_{2,j}}]=\prod_{j=1}^n\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X_{1,j}X_{2,j}}]=\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X_{1,1}X_{2,1}}]^n$ and further
$$\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X_{1,1}X_{2,1}}]
=\int\int\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2}e^{\lambda xy}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
=\sigma\int\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-\lambda x)^2}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}}\in\mathbb R_{\ge 1}$.
The inner integral is $1$ since the normal distribution is normalized, and then so is the outer, thus $\mathbb E[e^{\lambda X_{1,1}X_{2,1}}]=\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}}$ and thereby
$$P_+(n,t)\le\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}}^ne^{-\lambda tn}=e^{-f(t,\lambda)t^2n},$$
with $f(t,\lambda)$ from above (recall that $t>0$). Since this holds for any choice of $\lambda\in(0,1)$, we identify the optimal $\lambda$ by computing
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}(t,\lambda)=\frac{-\lambda}{t^2(1-\lambda^2)}+\frac{1}{t},$$
which is positive for $\lambda\rightarrow 0$ since $t$ is, and tends to $-\infty$ for $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$, so the only root given by $\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda^2}=t$, or [equivalently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) by $\lambda=\lambda(t)\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ (using $\lambda>0$), is a maximizer of $f$. This gives $P_+(n,t)\le e^{-f(t)t^2n}$ and further $P(n,t)\le 2e^{-f(t)t^2n}$ using that $X_1\cdot X_2$ and $-X_1\cdot X_2$ have the same law (since this holds for $X_1$ and $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent).
Aside, notice that we did not *have to* show that $\lambda(t)$ maximizes $f$, but of course we want to clarify why we made this choice.

Before we turn back to $|X^\circ_1\cdot X^\circ_2|$, let us take another brief look at $f(t)$.
Using l'Hôpital's rule, notice that $\lambda(0)=0$.
Further, notice that $\lambda'(t)=\frac{\sqrt{1+4t^2}-1}{2t^2\sqrt{1+4t^2}}$ and hence $\lambda'(0)=1$ by another application of l'Hôpital's rule.
Using l'Hôpital's rule for $g(t)=\lambda(t)/t$ at $t=0$ hence yields the continuation $g(0)=1$. Combining this with l'Hôpital's rule for $f$ gives
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{-2\lambda(t)\lambda'(t)}{4t(1-\lambda(t)^2)}+1
=-\frac{1}{2}+1=f(0),$$
so $f$ is continuous. So, let $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ be sufficiently small such that $f(t)(1-\varepsilon)^2\ge 1/4$ for $t\in[0,\varepsilon]$.

Now, consider the event $\mathcal E(n,t)=\{|X^\circ_1\cdot X^\circ_2|\ge t\}$.
For $t\in[0,1)$ we can write this as
$$\mathcal E(n,t)=\left\{\frac{|X_1\cdot X_2|}{Z_1Z_2}\ge\frac{(1-t)t}{\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{1-t}}\right\},$$
which implies that on $\mathcal E(n,t)$ we have $Z_1\le\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{n}$ or $Z_2\le\sqrt{1-t}\sqrt{n}$ or $|X_1\cdot X_2|\ge(1-t)tn$, since otherwise $\mathcal E(n,t)$ does not hold. Hence, the union bound and the above yield
\begin{aligned}
P^\circ(n,t)&\le\mathbb P(Z_1^2\le(1-t)n)+\mathbb P(Z_2^2\le(1-t)n)+\mathbb P(|X_1\cdot X_2|\ge(1-t)tn)\\
&\le 2e^{-\frac{1}{4}t^2n}+2e^{-f((1-t)t)((1-t)t)^2n}.
\end{aligned}
Now, for $t\in[\varepsilon,1]$ we use the bound
\begin{aligned}
P^\circ(n,t)
&\le P^\circ(n,\varepsilon)
\le 2e^{-\frac{1}{4}\varepsilon^2n}+2e^{-f((1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon)((1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon)^2n}
\le 2e^{-\frac{1}{4}\varepsilon^2n}+2e^{-f((1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon)((1-\varepsilon)\varepsilon)^2n}\\
&\le 4e^{-\frac{1}{4}\varepsilon^2 n}
\le 4e^{-\frac{1}{4}\varepsilon^2 t^2n}=ae^{-bt^2n},\,a=4,\,b=\varepsilon^2/4,
\end{aligned}
where we used that $t\le 1$. For $t>1$ we have $P(n,t)=0\le ae^{-bt^2n}$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. For $t\in[0,\varepsilon)$ we proceed analogously to the above to obtain
\begin{aligned}
P^\circ(n,t)\le 2e^{-\frac{1}{4}t^2n}+2e^{-f((1-t)t)((1-t)t)^2n}
\le ae^{-b't^2n},\,b'=1/4\ge b.
\end{aligned}
This shows that in any case we have $P^\circ(n,t)\le ae^{-bt^2n}$.

Aftermath: Clearly, we can significantly improve the constant $b$ by analyzing $f$.
A plot reveals that $f([0,1])=[f(1),0.5]$ with $f(1)\approx 0.377428$. Using the bound $f\ge f(1)$ and then optimizing the coefficient already gives $b=0.118$. Working with $f$ directly allows to further optimize the coefficient, if required.

Comment: But there is a problem. If I take $t=n^{-1/2}$, then in your bound $P(|u\cdot v|>n^{-1/2})\le ae^{-b}$ which does not dependent on $n$... I hope that this probability is 0 as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. The [CLT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554524/why-do-we-have-that-u-cdot-v-converges-weakly-to-a-standard-gaussian-random-va) suggests that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(|u\cdot v|<n^{-1/2})>0$, so *fortunately* we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}ae^{-b}=ae^{-b}>0$, otherwise the bound would necessarily be wrong.

Comment: Can you please see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578243/how-to-lower-bound-tau-based-on-the-expression-of-h?

Answer (score 0):

We know that $|u\cdot v| \leq 1$ by cauchy-schwarz, so $u\cdot v$ is subgaussian with parameter at most $1$. So we have the concentration:

$$\mathbb P \left ( |u \cdot v - \mathbb E [u \cdot v]| \geq t \right ) \leq e^{-t^2/2}$$

Comment: $E$ is zero I think. And hopefully it is possible to get something in terms of $n$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Why $E[u\cdot v]=0$?

Comment: How to remove $E[u\cdot v]$? Because I just want to get $P(u\cdot v\ge t)\le ...$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang If $u=[1,0,\dots, 0]=v$, then $u\cdot v=1$? So the expectation is 1.

Comment: @Hermi I am not sure how to prove this, but there is a lemma used to prove JL lemma that is useful here: https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/cs731/projection.pdf (see lemma 1)

Comment: Also see my question (from 2 years ago :) ) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922615/inner-product-of-unit-vector-with-a-vector-uniformly-distributed-on-a-hyperspher

Comment: @dmh $E[u\cdot v]=E[g\cdot h]/(\|g\|_2\|h\|_2)$ where $u=g/\|g\|_2$ for two Gaussian random vectors $h\sim N(0, I_n)$ and $g$. Since $g\cdot h=g_1h_1+\cdots g_nh_n$ and $E[g_1h_1]=E[g_1]E[h_2]=0$ then $E[u\cdot v]=0$. Doe it make sense?

Comment: unfortunately no, that's what makes this a tough problem. You do not know that $g$ and $\|g\|$ are independent, so you cannot compute the expectation separately.

Comment: @dmh Can we assume that $v=[1,0,\dots, 0]$? Then $u\cdot v=u_1$ so $E[u\cdot v]=E[u_1]=0$?

Comment: I mean just for simple and we assume that $v=e_1$. Then $u\cdot e_1=u_1$. But the issue is that $E[u_1]=?$.

Comment: @dmh Can you see Remark 3.2.5 in https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf?

Comment: The distributions of $u$ and $-u$ are the same. This easily implies that the expectation is zero.

Comment: @PhoemueX I did not understand. Can you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: @dmh: Can you please explain? Only $|u\cdot v|\le 1$ a.s. does not give the bound. We do not have $1-F(t)\le e^{-t^2/2}$ for *all* (continuous) cdfs $F$ with $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$ and $t\in[0,\infty)$. This is equivalent to $F(t)\ge 1-e^{-t^2/2}$, violated by any $F$ with $F(1/2)=0$ (or small enough). Thus, you also use some other argument. Which one? Further, $u\cdot v$ concentrates around $0$, the pdf of $\sqrt{n}u\cdot v$ can be dominated by a Gaussian function (what I call sub-gaussian *concentration*). Your bound doesn't depend on $n$, it doesn't give concentration.

Comment: @Matija Why $|u\cdot v|\le 1$ does not give the bound? That means this random variable is bounded by 1 so it is sub-Gaussian.

Comment: I see that it is sub-Gaussian for $ee^{-t^2}$, i.e. parameters $e$ and $1$, which gives a trivial bound (meaning $\ge 1$), best possible unless we make further assumptions (as argued before), I don't see why it's sub-Gaussian with parameters $1$ and $1/2$ as claimed. And most of all, I don't see why this bound is relevant in the context of concentration (cf. title of the question).

Comment: @Matija, I showed it is bounded. All bounded random variables are subgaussian.

Comment: I see that it is subgaussian for $ee^{-t^2}$, i.e. parameters $e$ and $1$. I don't see why it's subgaussian with parameters $1$ and $1/2$. Counterexamples can be found above.

Comment: The counterexample given will not have an expectation of $0$

Comment: Well: $\mathbb E[|u\cdot v|]>0$. Also, usually results have to be proven. A result is not true until proven otherwise, it's the other way around.