# Why do we have that $u\cdot v$ converges weakly to a standard Gaussian random variables as $n\to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

Following this question: [Can we get the concentration inequality of the inner product of two unit vectors distributed on the sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553074/can-we-get-the-concentration-inequality-of-the-inner-product-of-two-unit-vectors).

Let $u$ and $v$ be two random vectors on $R^n$ that are independent and uniformly distributed on the unit sphere. That means we can represent it as Gaussian random vectors $g\sim N(0, I_n)$, $$u=\frac{g}{\|g\|_2}.
$$

Why do we have that $u\cdot v$ (may be with some orders?) converges weakly to a standard Gaussian random variables as $n\to \infty$? That means $u\cdot v=O_p(1)$.

Comment: Distribution definition is confusing.  Uniform, Gaussian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also write $v = h/\lVert h \rVert_2$ for Gaussian $h$.
We then have that
$$
u\cdot v
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n g_i h_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n g_i^2 \sum_{i=1}^n h_i^2}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n g_i h_i}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g_i^2 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h_i^2}}.
$$

By the CLT, the numerator converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, whereas by the LLN, the denominator converges in probability to $1$.

Therefore, Slutsky's theorem yields that
$$
\sqrt{n}(u\cdot v)
= \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n g_i h_i}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g_i^2 \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h_i^2}}
\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}\mathcal{N}(0, 1).
$$

---

By the way, the intuition here is that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the norm of an $n$-dimensional Gaussian random vector concentrates around $\sqrt{n}$, and so such a random vector can be thought of as being very similar to a random vector uniformly distributed on the $(n-1)$-sphere of radius $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I'm just too slow. But doesn't the squared norm concentrate around $n$?

Comment: Thank you! So we have $u\cdot v=O_p(n^{-1/2})$?

Comment: @Matija Whoops, yes - that's right of course! Should be fixed now

Comment: @Hermi Yes, that's correct. For any sequences $\{X_n\}$ of RVs and $\{a_n\}$ or real numbers, $a_n X_n$ converging in distribution implies that $X_n = O_{\Pr}(a_n^{-1})$.

Comment: We divide by $n$ to take both lengths into account, and without the normalization we would have to scale with $1/\sqrt{n}$, so $\sqrt{n}$ scaling for the CLT seems fine.