# What is the order of the ration of two asymptotic Gaussian random vectors?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $A$ be a real Gaussian random matrix. Ordering its eigenvalues $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge \dots\ge \lambda_n$ corresponding eigenvectors $v_1, v_2,\dots, v_n$. We know that $v_i$ are uniformly distributed on the sphere. Let $u$ be a vector uniformly distributed on the sphere.

Based on this question [Why do we have that $u\cdot v$ converges weakly to a standard Gaussian random variables as $n\to \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554524/why-do-we-have-that-u-cdot-v-converges-weakly-to-a-standard-gaussian-random-va), we know that
$$
\sqrt{n}(u\cdot v_1)\to^d N(0,1)
$$
and
$$\sqrt{n}(u\cdot v_2)\to^d N(0,1)$$

So we have $u\cdot v_1=O_p(n^{-1/2})$ and $u\cdot v_2=O_p(n^{-1/2})$.

Question:
But can we say that
$$
\frac{u\cdot v_2}{u\cdot v_1}\to^d N(0,1)?
$$

Or what is the order of $\frac{u\cdot v_2}{u\cdot v_1}$?