# How to lower bound $\tau$ based on the expression of $H$?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, inequality

Let $A=\{a_{ij}\}_{1\le i,j\le n}$ be an $n$ by $n$ normalized symmetric Gaussian random matrix with $E[a_{ij}]=0$ and $E[a_{ij}^2]=1/n$. Ordering its eigenvalues by $\lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \cdots \lambda_n$ with corresponding eigenvectors $v_1,\dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $u_0$ be a vector on $\mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly distributed on the unit sphere. (We also know that $v_i$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere for $i=1,\dots, n$.)

Define $H_j(t)=u_t\cdot v_j$ for $j=1,\dots, n$ and time $t\ge 0$, solving the following ODE with initial value $H_j(0)$:
$$
\frac{1}{2}H_j'(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n[(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)H_i^2(t)]H_j(t)
$$

Comment: There is an error, you should replace $\lambda_2$ by $\lambda_n$ for the upper bound. The right formula should be
$$
H_1^2(t)\le \frac{1}{1+(H_1^{-2}(0)-1)e^{-4t(\lambda_\color{red}{n}-\lambda_1)}}
$$

Comment: Is  this statement from a reliable source ? 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}P(\tau_\epsilon\ge n^{2/3})=1.
$$
Are you sure that it is correct?

Comment: @NN2 In here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434736/how-to-get-the-lower-bound-of-the-following-tau. Do you think that solution makes sense?

Comment: I found that  in this question, $\lambda_i$ are random variables (in the previous question that I answered you, $b_i \in \mathbb{R}$) . If we bound $H_1(t)$, we assume that $\lambda_i = \lambda_j$ for at least a couple $(i,j)$,  for example $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3=...=\lambda_n  \qquad  (1)$. The probability that $(1)$ occurs is almost surely $0$. Perhaps that's reason why it is not possible to prove your question by seeking a bound

Comment: I don't know whether seeking an upper bound works.

Comment: @NN2 I added one simple proof of the lower bound of $H_{n-1}(t)$. Do you think that works?

Comment: The matrix A is not symmetric, why would all the eigenvalues be real (and therefore admit an ordering)?

Comment: Or are we really just working with some exotic weighted average on the unit sphere? The sum of Hi(t) being 1 for all t also looks dubious to me.

Comment: I think we might be missing information about the choice of $u_0$; it will affect the convergence time, and it seems only specific choices would allow "fact" 3 to be true (this is an assumption, not a fact). Furthermore, thinking about particular cases when $\lambda_1 \geq 0$: the choice $u_0 = -v_1$ is clearly the slowest case so I would say there is loss of generality assuming that all $H_i(0)$ are positive; and with the choice $u_0 = v_1$ the inequality you're trying to prove is clearly wrong (so it is wrong in a neighborhood of nonzero measure).

Answer (score 0):

Let us drop the calculations and formalism for a minute, and think about this problem geometrically.

We know the eigenvectors $v_1, ..., v_n$ are orthogonal, and correspond to $n$ points on the unit sphere, i.e. $\forall j,\ \|v_j\| = 1$. Since $u_0$ also has norm 1, the function $H_j(0)$ is the cosine of the angle $\alpha_j(0)$ between $u_0$ and $v_j$ [1]:
$$
  H_j(0) = u_0\cdot v_j = \|u_0\|\|v_j\|\cos\alpha_j(0) = \cos\alpha_j(0)
$$

Now consider the ODE for $H_1$:
$$
  H_1^\prime(t) = 2H_1(t)\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i - \lambda_1)H_i(t)^2
$$

For $u_0 = v_1$, we have $H_1(0) = 1$, and since the eigenvectors are orthogonal $H_i(0) = 0$ for all $i > 1$. Hence $H_1^\prime(0) = 0$, and it follows that $H_1^\prime(t) = 0$ for all $t$, i.e. $v_1$ is an invariant. Furthermore because in this case $H_1(t)=1$ is maximal, we have $\tau_\varepsilon = 0 < n^{2/3}$, and at least one counter-example to the proposition [2].

However to disprove the proposition, a single counter-example is not sufficient (the measure of a finite set is zero). Next we will show that $\tau_\varepsilon < n^{2/3}$ in a neighborhood of $v_1$ for any threshold $\varepsilon$ and dimension $n$.

Pick a threshold $0 < \varepsilon \leq 1$. Since $\lambda_i - \lambda_1 \geq 0$ for all $i$, all of the terms in the formula of the derivative $H_1^\prime$ above are non-negative, and therefore if we pick $u_0$ such that $H_1(0)\geq 0$ we have:
$$ \forall t\geq 0,\ H_1(t)\geq H_1(0) = \cos\alpha_1(0) $$
Hence for any choice of $u_0$ at a small enough angle from $v_1$ such that $0\leq \alpha_1(0) \leq \cos^{-1}\varepsilon$, we have:
$$
\forall t\geq 0,\quad H_1(t)\geq H_1(0) = \cos\alpha_1(0) \geq \varepsilon 
\quad\implies\quad
\tau_\varepsilon = 0 
$$
proving that $\tau_\varepsilon < n^{2/3}$ occurs with non-zero probability for any dimension $n$ and threshold $\varepsilon$, i.e. $P( \tau_\varepsilon < n^{2/3}) > 0$.

[1] Note that the only way to satisfy the assumption $\sum_{i=1}^nH_i(t)^2 = 1$ for all $t$ is to allow $\| u_t \| \leq 1$. So in general $H_j(t) = \|u_t\|\cos\alpha_j(t)$.
[2] Naturally I am assuming $\varepsilon \leq 1$.

Comment: I have shown that $\forall n, \varepsilon,\ P(\tau_\varepsilon < n^{2/3}) > 0$, so the consequence is that $P(\tau_\varepsilon \geq n^{2/3}) < 1$, which disproves the proposition. I haven’t explicitly taken this to the limit of infinite dimensions but I don’t see how the result would be any different, do you? As for $\tau_{1-\varepsilon}$, nothing changes there either, it’s just another way of defining a threshold; everything above is also valid for the threshold $\eta = 1-\varepsilon$.

Comment: Well, I do not think that is an issue. I am looking for a probabilistic answer; it is easy to construct exceptions to the inequalities, but these are harmless because they have a probability that tends to zero in the large-n limit; in the "counter example" you constructed the $H_i(0)$ are all equal to zero if $I\neq 1$; the probability for that to happen has measure zero.

Comment: The vector $u_0$ is chosen independently of $v_1$ and uniformly distributed on the sphere. WLOG, $v_1=(1,0,\dots,0)$, you want the first component of $u_0$ close to 1. But  the distribution of $u_0$ and $v_1$ is Gaussian centered at 0 with variance $1/n$. So for $n>>1$, the probability to find it close to 1 vanishes as $e^{-n/2}$.

Comment: @Hermi "But the distribution of $u_0$ and $v_1$ is Gaussian centred at 0 with variance 1/n." Nonsense, you said that $u_0$ was uniformly distributed on the unit sphere.

Comment: @Hermi "it is easy to construct exceptions to the inequalities, but these are harmless because they have a probability that tends to zero in the large-n limit" Have you read the second part of my answer? In no uncertain terms, I have shown that there is always a non-singular area on the unit sphere from which if we draw $u_0$, then $\tau_\varepsilon =0$.

Comment: @Hermi What I wrote above proves that your proposition is wrong. Would you like me to find the mistakes in your attempts? There might be a different way to define $\tau_\varepsilon$ which would focus the problem on what I think you're after.

Comment: @Hermi We cannot, because it is not true :) The problem really isn't that complicated; we have a smooth non-decreasing function bounded from above, so we know it converges. Your proposition is equivalent to saying that it almost always takes more than a certain time to get within some margin of the asymptote. My proof simply says that for any given margin, there is a non-zero probability to start within the margin of the asymptotic value, in which case the time it takes to get there is zero. So the proposition is wrong. Does that make sense?

Comment: I do not think so. Because we need to find a probabilistic answer. I have already explained this in that comments.

Comment: @Hermi It is a probabilistic argument to say that there is a non-zero probability to fall within the margin, isn't it?

Comment: $u_0$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere and $v_1$ is also random. So $u_0\cdot v_1$ are $N(0,1/n)$. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554524/why-do-we-have-that-u-cdot-v-converges-weakly-to-a-standard-gaussian-random-va for a proof.

Comment: @Hermi And all I am saying is that the probability that $u_0$ falls within a certain angle of $v_1$ is always non-zero regardless of the dimension $n$, in which case $\tau_\epsilon = 0$, which contradicts the proposition.

Comment: @Hermi It does not matter that it is chosen independently from $v_1$ or not, the probability to fall within a certain angle of $v_1$ is always positive.

Comment: @Hermi "But the distribution of u0 and v1 is Gaussian centered at 0 with variance 1/n." This makes no sense by the way, both $u_0$ and $v_1$ always have norm 1. They are uniformly distributed on the sphere, not Gaussian distributed. And I don't know what you mean by variance 1/n when talking about vectors.

Comment: @Hermi I agree with the proof until:
$$
\tau_\varepsilon \geq \frac{\log\varepsilon - \log |H_1(0)|}{2(\lambda_n - \lambda_1)}
$$
where the rhs is negative whenever $|H_1(0)|\geq\varepsilon$ (which always happens with non-zero probability). I don't understand how you get from there to $C\log(\varepsilon n)$ though, wouldn't that mean $\tau_\varepsilon$ becomes infinitely large as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Hermi No, I only agree with the inequality that I wrote in my previous message, not $C\log(\varepsilon n)$. I think $H_1(0) = \mathcal{O}(n^{-1/2})$ is wrong; I don't see a reason for the cosine of the angle between $u_0$ and $v_1$ to depend on the dimension $n$, do you have a proof for that?