# Is there any other way to get upper bound of the ration of the weighted summation?

Tags: analysis, inequality

Fix some constants $c_1, c_2,\dots, c_n$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2=1$ and $|c_i|\le 1$ for $i=1,\dots, n$, and $-2\le b_1\le \dots \le b_n\le 2$.

I want to upper bound the following equation
$$
L=\frac{c_1^2e^{-4b_1t}}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 e^{-4b_it}}.
$$

It is clear that $L\le 1$.

(1) One trivial upper bound is that since $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 e^{-4b_it}\ge c_2^2 e^{-4b_2t}$, so we have that
$$
L\le \frac{c_1^2e^{-4b_1t}}{c_2^2e^{-4b_2t}}\le \frac{e^{-4b_1t}}{c_2^2e^{-4b_2t}}
$$

But I don't want to have a proportionality constant like $c_1^2/c_2^2$ or $1/c_2^2$ for some reason.

Question: Is there any other way to get its upper bound? The coefficients depend only on $c_1$ or $c_i$, not on the ratio of constants $c_i$.

Comment: You can try AM-GM in the denominator and obtain something else.

Comment: @openspace Can you explain more? I find this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means. But here the denominator is weighted, is there a similar one?

Comment: You need to bound the denominator with the minimal value. Ones try to compute: $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 e^{-4b_i t} \ge n \left(\prod_i c_i^2 e^{-4b_i t}\right)^{1/n}$.

Comment: Actually, there is a weighted one for your case: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/AM-GM_Inequality

Comment: @openspace But this doesn't get the results I want. The denominator part will still have $c_1, c_2, \dots...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solve a more general problem by finding the upper bound of
$$L=\frac{c_\color{blue}{k}^2e^{-4b_\color{blue}{k}t}}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 e^{-4b_it}} \qquad \quad \text{for }0\le k\le n$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
L &= \frac{c_k^2e^{-4b_kt}}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 e^{-4b_it}}=\frac{c_k^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2 e^{-4(b_i-b_k)t}}=\frac{c_k^2}{\sum_{i<k} c_i^2 e^{-4(b_i-b_k)t}+c_k^2+\sum_{i>k} c_i^2 e^{-4(b_i-b_k)t}}\\
\end{align}$$
As $-2\le b_1 \le ...\le b_n \le 2$, we have : $-4 \le b_i- b_k \le 0$ for $i<k$ and $0 \le b_i- b_k \le 4$ for $i>k$, we deduce that
$$e^{-4(b_i-b_k)t}\ge 1 \qquad \text{     for }i <k$$
$$e^{-4(b_i-b_k)t}\ge e^{-16t} \qquad \text{for }i >k$$
Then
$$L \le \frac{c_k^2}{\left(\sum_{i<k} c_i^2\right) +c_k^2+\left(\sum_{i>k} c_i^2\right) e^{-16t}} =\frac{c_k^2}{\left(\sum_{i \le k} c_i^2\right)+\left(1-\left(\sum_{i \le k} c_i^2\right)\right) e^{-16t}}$$
The equality occurs when $b_1 = ...=b_k=-2$ and $b_{k+1}=...=b_n=2$.

**Remark**: By the same method, the lower bound is
$$L \ge \frac{c_k^2}{\left(\sum_{i < k} c_i^2\right)e^{16t} +1-\sum_{i < k} c_i^2 }$$
when $b_1 = ...=b_{k-1}=-2$ and $b_{k}=...=b_n=2$

For your initial problem,
$$\color{red}{L \le \frac{c_1^2}{c_1^2+\left(1-c_1^2\right) e^{-16t}}}$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually concerned about this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578243/how-to-lower-bound-the-hitting-time-based-on-the-expression, so I guess maybe I need the denominator to not have these constants, but the numerator to have them. I'm not sure if I can do this?

Comment: If possible, can you please see that question? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hermi You're welcome. For your question, I don't think you can. First, the bound is already as tight as possible because there is the equality. Second, we need to remind that $c_i$ or $H_j(0)$ are constant and **known** input and it seems meaningless to seek a bound for a **known** value. Besides, this weekend I'm little busy but I'll look at your others questions for sure.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578243/how-to-lower-bound-tau-based-on-the-expression-of-h based on your answer.