# Can we find $C>1$ so that $ P(|X|\le \frac{\epsilon}{C})\ge 1-\delta $?

Tags: probability

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Consider two $n-$dimensional random vectors $u$ and $v$ uniformly distributed on the sphere. Define $X_n :=u\cdot v$. Note that as $n\to \infty$, $\sqrt{n}X_n \to N(0,1)$ by [Why do we have that $u\cdot v$ converges weakly to a standard Gaussian random variables as $n\to \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554524/why-do-we-have-that-u-cdot-v-converges-weakly-to-a-standard-gaussian-random-va).

So we have $\sqrt{n}X_n \sim N(0,1)$ and $|X_n|\le 1$.

Can we show that for any $\delta>0$,
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n|\le \epsilon)\ge 1-\delta ?
$$

Or moreover can we show that for any $\delta>0$, there exists $C>1$ such that
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n|\le \epsilon/C)\ge 1-\delta ?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y \sim N(0,1).$
Then for every $\delta \in (0,1)$, there exists a large number $M$ such that $P(|Y| < M) \ge 1-\delta$.

Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_0$ such that for every $n \ge N_0$, $\sqrt{n} \epsilon > M$.

Hence, for every $n \ge N_0$,
$$ P(|X_n| \le \epsilon) = P(\sqrt{n}|X_n| \le \sqrt{n}\epsilon) \ge P(\sqrt{n}|X_n| < M).$$

By characterization of weak convergences,
$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} P(\sqrt{n}|X_n| < M) \ge P(|Y| < M) \ge 1-\delta.$$

Comment: $|X| < 1$ and $X \sim N(0, 1/n)$ are not compatible with each other, because if $X$ follows one-dimensional Normal distribution, it is supported on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What? If we consider two $n$ dimensional random vectors $u$ and $v$ uniformly distributed on the unit sphere on $R^n$. Let $X:=u\cdot v$. Then $\sqrt{n}X\to N(0,1)$ by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554524/why-do-we-have-that-u-cdot-v-converges-weakly-to-a-standard-gaussian-random-va. Why this is not compatible?

Comment: @Hermi, I do not see why multidimensional distributions appear.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrite my question and it maybe clear now.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible for you to see my other related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578243/how-to-lower-bound-tau-based-on-the-expression-of-h?

Comment: Also, can I ask why do you take the $\lim \inf$ but not $\lim$?

Comment: This is a minor problem. We can replace the liminf with  the lim, because the limit distribution (here the standard normal N(0,1)) is continuous.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why the first statement holds?

Comment: Can we prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(\sqrt{n}|X_n|\le \epsilon)\ge 1-\delta$?

Comment: That does not hold.

Comment: Can I ask a question about your first statement? Do you say that for any non-negative random variable $Y$, we always have this statement: for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a constant $M$ such that $P(Y<M)\ge 1-\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, assuming $Y$ does not take $\infty$.