# Can we show that for every $\delta>0$, there exist constants $\alpha>0, \beta>0$ so that the following inequality holds with high probability?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, inequality

Consider two $n-$dimensional random vectors $u$ and $v$ uniformly distributed on the sphere. Define $X_n :=u\cdot v$. Note that as $n\to \infty$, $\sqrt{n}X_n \to N(0,1)$ as $n\to \infty$. Fix $\epsilon>0$ (very small).

Can we show that for every $\delta>0$, there exist constants $\alpha>0, \beta>0$ so that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}P\left(\frac{X_n^{-2}-1}{\epsilon^{-2}-1}<\alpha n^\beta\right)\ge 1-\delta.
$$

Or can we revise this upper bound for $\frac{X_n^{-2}-1}{\epsilon^{-2}-1}$ depending on $n$.

Since we know that the order $X_n=O_p(n^{-1/2})$, then the order of $\frac{X_n^{-2}-1}{\epsilon^{-2}-1}$ is about $O_p(n)$. But I am stuck on how get the strict upper bound. (Maybe this question would be helpful: [Can we find $C>1$ so that $ P(|X|\le \frac{\epsilon}{C})\ge 1-\delta $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593238/can-we-find-c1-so-that-px-le-frac-epsilonc-ge-1-delta?))

---

Let $Y\sim N(0,1)$ (hence we can write $X_n=n^{-1/2}Y$. Note that
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}P\left(\frac{X_n^{-2}-1}{\epsilon^{-2}-1}<\alpha n^\beta\right)&=P\left(n\frac{Y^{-2}-1}{\epsilon^{-2}-1}<\alpha n^\beta\right)\\&=P\left(nY^{-2}<\alpha(\epsilon^{-2}-1)n^{\beta}+1\right)\\&=P\left(Y^2>\frac{n}{\alpha(\epsilon^{-2}-1)n^{\beta}+1}\right)\end{align*}
$$

I am not sure if we can apply the concentration result of the Gaussian variable to find proper $\alpha, \beta>0$ so that this probability larger than $1-\delta$.

Comment: In our community, there are experts on "distributions on spheres", but they might miss your question. You might want to change the title or tags.

Comment: @iljusch Well, this question is not much related to the uniformly distributed of the sphere. We can think about that is an asymptotic normal random variable.

Comment: I agree. I would still recommend a more expressive title (also for future researchers who look for similar answers as you do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}$
Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, $\delta > 0$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$.
Then there exists $\xi > 0$ ("small") such that $\bP(|Y|>\xi) \geq 1-\delta$.
Choose $\alpha = (\xi^2(\varepsilon^{-2}-1))^{-1} > 0$ and $\beta = 1$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{X_{n}^{-2}-1}{\varepsilon^{-2}-1}
<
\alpha n^{\beta}
&\Longleftrightarrow
|X_{n}|^{-2}
<
1 + \xi^{-2} n
\\
&\Longleftrightarrow
|X_{n}|
>
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \xi^{-2} n}}
=
\frac{\xi}{\xi^{2}+n}
\\
&\Longleftrightarrow
\sqrt{\frac{\xi^{2}+n}{n}} \, \sqrt{n} |X_{n}|
>
\xi
\end{align*}
Since $a_{n} := \sqrt{\frac{\xi^{2}+n}{n}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$ and $\sqrt{n}X_{n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} Y$, we obtain $a_{n}\sqrt{n}X_{n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} Y$ and therefore
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \bP\bigg(\frac{X^{-2}-1}{\varepsilon^{-2}-1}<\alpha n^{\beta}\bigg)
=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \bP(a_{n} \sqrt{n} |X_{n}| > \xi)
=
\bP(|Y| > \xi)
\geq
1-\delta.
$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask where can I find the reference for this result "Then there exists $\xi > 0$ ("small") such that $P(|Y|>\xi) \geq 1-\delta$."?

Comment: Also, can we ensure that $\alpha n^{\beta}>1$ in your proof? Thank you!

Comment: Since $\exp(-x^2/2) \leq 1$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $\mathbb{P}(|Y|\leq \xi) = (2\pi)^{-1/2} \int_{-\xi}^{\xi} \exp(-x^2/2) \, \mathrm{d}x \leq (2\pi)^{-1/2} \, 2\xi$.
Hence, for sufficiently small $\xi>0$, this probability will be smaller than $\delta$ (namely for $0 < \xi < (2\pi)^{1/2} \delta/2$).

Comment: Concerning your last question: $\alpha n^{\beta} > 1$ obviously holds for large $n$, but you can even ensure this for *each* $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Once you have found $\xi > 0$ with the property $\mathbb{P}(|Y|>\xi) \geq 1-\delta$, this property will obviously hold for every smaller $\tilde{\xi} > 0$ as well. Hence you can choose $0 < \tilde{\xi} < \xi$ such that $\alpha = (\tilde{\xi} ^2(\varepsilon^{-2}-1))^{-1} > 1$ and work with this $\tilde{\xi}$ and $\alpha$ instead.

Comment: Thank you very much!